# set default router if method not specified

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, routing, router

I have a custom module inside my local code pool and folder structure for the same is as below:

```
app
  code
     local
        namespace
           module
               controllers
               etc
etc
   modules
      namespace_module.xml
```

namespace_module.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

namespace/module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <module>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                    <frontName>module</frontName>
                </args>
            </module>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

controllers/UploadController.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_UploadController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "Hi Buddy.."; die();
    }

}
```

If I run the url as below,

http://myhost/project/module/upload

it access the indexAction()

But if I dont mention the controller name, it should access indexAction of the uploadCOntroller, How can I do this? I mean if I run below url

http://myhost/project/module/

it should access uploadcontroller/index action/

Comment: You need to know the `indexAction` is redirect automatically ?

Comment: I know that @MeenakshiSundaramR check my updated question, I think I am not explained clearly. Check last two lines added

Comment: downvoter reason please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new Url Rewrite Rule in admin panel.

navigate to

> admin > catalog > Url Rewrite management

Click `Add Url Rewrite` button Then create Url Rewrite as `custom`

here Id path will be unique name

```
Requested Path : module

Target Path : module/upload/index

Redirect : No
```

That's it.

Refer this [**Link**](http://blog.beetleweb.com/2012/10/creating-custom-magento-url-rewrites/)